# Linux tools - how to count and list occurrences of regex in file

Tags: regex, linux

I have a file with a large number of similar strings.  I want to count unique occurrences of a regex, and also show what they were, e.g. for the pattern `Profile: (\w*)` on the file:

```
Profile: blah
Profile: another
Profile: trees
Profile: blah
```

I want to find that there are 3 occurrences, and return the results:

```
blah, another, trees
```

Comment: @Stefen I assume `NoMatch: nomatch` line should not appear in result. Please confirm. If so please add such negative strings also in the example so that you don't get false pass

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
egrep "Profile: (\w*)" test.text -o | sed 's/Profile: \(\w*\)/\1/g' | sort | uniq
```

Output:

```
another
blah
trees
```

**Description**

`egrep` with `-o` option will fetch matching pattern within a file.

`sed` will only fetch capturing part

`sort` followed by `uniq` will give a list of unique elements

To get number of elements in resultant list, append the command with `wc -l`

```
egrep "Profile: (\w*)" test.text -o | sed 's/Profile: \(\w*\)/\1/g' | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: +1 for returning the correct list, only half an answer since it doesn't return the count

Comment: well this solution works.. personally I don't like the combination of `grep|sed|sort|uniq` four processes...  if OP wants the count, I guess `wc` could join the party?

Comment: @Stefan thanks for pointing out. I was just updating post with description and extension

Comment: @Kent I would be interested in knowing concise solution. But personally I like simplicity and readability rather than remembering complex combination of options with single utility

Comment: @jkshah to be honest, your solution is a kind of complex combination of commands and options. think about it `I have a file with a large number of similar strings` if the file has 100 millions lines, how many times you have to process those lines to get your first output. and to get the count, you double the times again. well, as I said, my personal opinion. your commands worked for the example in this question.

Comment: @Kent Well I completely agree with you. I have had faced processing overhead issues with large files. But I am also kinda beginner and keen to know the optimal solution. I see that you have used `awk` and will try to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{a[$2]}END{for(x in a)print x}' file
```

will work on your example

```
kent$  echo "Profile: blah
Profile: another
Profile: trees
Profile: blah"|awk '{a[$2]}END{for(x in a)print x}'
another
trees
blah
```

if you want to have the count (3) in output:

```
awk '{a[$2]}END{print "count:",length(a);for(x in a)print x }' file
```

with same example:

```
kent$  echo "Profile: blah
Profile: another
Profile: trees
Profile: blah"|awk '{a[$2]}END{print "count:",length(a);for(x in a)print x }'
count: 3
another
trees
blah
```

Comment: +1 for considering efficiency. While I agree your answer is more concise, and could be more efficient, it was actually easier to parse jkshah's answer to understand where to replace his variables with the ones I want, e.g. the regex string.

Comment: @Kent this fails with addition of `Nomatch: nomatch` and produces a false pass. Here OP wants lines with matching only `Profile: (\w*)`

Comment: @Kent Does this use any regex? I am totally unfamiliar with `awk`

Comment: @jkshah maybe you are right. A pattern should be checked. It would be very easy to be added to the one liner. Based on the example data in question, we don't need regexp.

Comment: @Kent Aha! based on this assumption of example data I could have removed `grep` then ;) `sed|sort|uniq` will only work